# How can I find the 9 fixed DCT coefficients instead of a number equal to the block size?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix-multiplication, dct

I want to find fixed 9 DCT coeffecients but it is giving coeffecient which is equal to block size.

I have tried the following code:

```
BlkSize=4
%figure, subplot(1,2,1)
%imagesc(Image),colormap gray,hold on
Image=double(Image);
dim=size(Image);
D=dctmtx(BlkSize);
figure, subplot(1,2,1)
imagesc(Image),colormap gray,hold on
subplot(1,2,2)
imagesc(Image),colormap gray,hold on
[X,Y]=genXYforDCT(3);
n=1;
h=[];
pause

 for x=1:ceil(BlkSize/2):dim(1)-BlkSize/2-1
   for y=1:ceil(BlkSize/2):dim(2)-BlkSize/2-1
        subplot(1,2,1),hold on
        set(h,'LineWidth',1) 
        h=plot([x x+BlkSize x+BlkSize x x],[y y y+BlkSize y+BlkSize y],'r');
        set(h,'LineWidth',3) 
        drawnow,pause(0.3)
        B{n} = Image(x:x+BlkSize/4-1,y:y+BlkSize/4-1);%%% changed
        CoefMtx=D*B{n}*D';
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! You do not ask a question in your post, can you please edit to add some relevant info? Does the code you posted works or fails? What is the error? What is your issue? You should change your title to something cleaner and describe your issue in the body of your question. Also, adding a tag with the language you are using will help relevant people see your question. Looks like matlab? But mentionned nowhere! Cheers!

Comment: It's hard to help with your code when is it not reproducible. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve